# Issue with HypMenuVRefresh

Tags: excel, vba, smartview

My VBA macros works stable in Excel 2010 enveronment. But if I runing it in Excel 2016, then I catch an error in HypMenuVRefresh command "Smart View handled an unknown exception thrown by Microsoft Office". I test it on different SV versions. In both cases I use MS Office 32bit.

Comment: Maybe the installation was not right? Did you try to uninstall all versions of SV and re-add the latest COM addin for SmartView?

Comment: You may also try what is suggested in https://www.databaseusers.com/article/5980183/